# Pandas groupby count values in aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

| Time | ID | OKEY | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 0 | OK | BLUE |
| 2021-05-05 19:16 | 1 | NOT_OK | BLUE |
| 2021-05-05 19:17 | 2 | NOT_OK | YELLOW |
| 2021-05-05 19:17 | 1 | OK | RED |

What would be the most efficient way of grouping by Id and then count every type of value in columns ('OKEY','COLOR') ?

I've tried using this so far:

```
df.set_index('Time')
df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='1min')]).agg(COUNT OKEY=('OKEY', 'count'),total_status=('COLOR', 'count'))
```

But I can only get the total count of all OK,NOT_OKEY / BLUE,YELLOW.. values.
I'd like to use value_counts() or any similar function to return a column or index with each type's  count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

Encode the columns `OKEY` and `COLOR` to convert the categorical values into indicator variables, then group the encoded frame by `ID` and 1 minute `Grouper` and `sum` the values per group

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['ID', "Time"]))\
  .groupby(['ID',  pd.Grouper(freq='1min', level=1)]).sum()
```

---

```
                        OKEY_NOT_OK  OKEY_OK  COLOR_BLUE  COLOR_RED  COLOR_YELLOW
ID Time                                                                          
0  2021-05-05 19:16:00            0        1           1          0             0
1  2021-05-05 19:16:00            1        0           1          0             0
   2021-05-05 19:17:00            0        1           0          1             0
2  2021-05-05 19:17:00            1        0           0          0             1
```